# Is there a way to copy certain parts of a formula down a column in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm creating a Google Sheet documenting how many times a certain item appears in a video game with the formula in the D column (formatted to a percent):

```
=IFERROR(C2/SUM(C2:C51))
```

I want the "C2" cell to apply down the column (C3, then C4, you get the idea), but I want the "C2:C51" array to stay constant while the C2 part gets applied down the down the column. How could I modify the formula to do this? (I could manually edit the formulas all the way down, I only have 50 rows, but I think it would be helpful to learn for the future)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`=iferror(C2 / sum(C$2:C$51))`

See [absolute and relative references](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/googlespreadsheets/types-of-cell-references/1/).

Alternatively, try this array formula that fills a whole column in one go:

`=arrayformula(iferror(C2:C51 / sum(C2:C51)))`